# See if an app has Apple Watch support via API?

Tags: itunes

I'm using the iTunes API too lookup some info about apps. I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to find out if the app has an Apple Watch companinion app or not via this API.

https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=705350439

This app has a text on it on the store page that says "Offers Apple Watch App for iPhone" and also some Apple Watch screenshots. But they doesn't seem to show up in the API.

Comment: I'd love to know if this is possible as well. I've scoured the data set results and I don't see anything.

Comment: This does not seem to be possible with the [Apple API](https://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html), but you could create your own API by scraping the website. Here are a couple example calls using an On-Demand API from Kimono Labs: `curl "https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/ondemand/20ccppyk?kimpath3=id375380948"` and `curl "https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/ondemand/20ccppyk?kimpath3=id377298193"`. There are other services like ScraperWiki that will achieve the same thing.